# Cannot open any website in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1

**OS** :: Windows 8.1 Pro x64

I installed Firefox Quantum 60.0 64bit

Following message is displayed when I try to open **any** website.

[image]

I tried

1. Proxy settings
2. Create new profile
3. Refresh firefox
4. Deleting all browsing data (though it was new installation).
5. Restarted system

Any other thing i can try to make it work:

**Update** All other browsers (Chrome and IE) are working without any issue. Also, Firefox has no issue opening intranet URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this for pretty much all secure sites, the problem usually is one of the following:

(1) Error in your system's date, time, or time zone, which throws off certificate validity checks. Sometimes allowing computers to use an internet-based time source can introduce this problem.

(2) Firefox not being set up to work with your security software that intercepts and filters secure connections. Products with this feature include Avast, BitDefender, Bullguard, ESET, and Kaspersky; AVG LinkScanner / SurfShield can cause this error on search sites.

If you have any of those specific security products: check this support article: [How to troubleshoot the error code "SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER" on secure websites.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)

(3) On Windows 10, Firefox not being set up to work with the parental control software Microsoft Family Safety. (To test by turning it off, see: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/wi.../turn-off-microsoft-family-settings)

(4) Malware on your system intercepting secure connections.

Comment: #2 helped me. Turns out that the reason was Monitoring/filtering in corporate networks. However, I still do not get why other browsers were working.